# Multi-level modelling in SPSS linking two groups?

Tags: spss, multilevel-analysis

I have a dataset with about 500 people. All of them are technically managers, but some of them manage one another within the dataset. I have a column that shows who manages who (Manager ID; there are about 200 managers and the rest are their followers).

All of the respondents answered questions about the vision for their team, and then all of them answered questions about their own job satisfaction.  I want to find out whether leaders who have a vision for their team have more satisfied followers.  So all of the followers answered vision questions, and all of the managers answered the job satisfaction questions, but I’m not interested in those (right now).  Instead, I want to know whether the leader’s vision influences the followers’ job satisfaction, and I think that I can do that with my linking `ManagerID` variable.

I am using Andy Field’s textbook as a guide, and so I use the mixed dropdown in SPSS, with `ManagerID` as the ‘subject’, dependent variable=job satisfaction, covariate=vision.  Under ‘fixed’ I move over vision to the model, and then under ‘random’ I move vision to the model, and put `ManagerID` as the combination.

For some reason, I don’t think that I’m doing this correctly. Any suggestions?